# subdomain of localhost is not working with express-subdomain

Tags: node.js, express, localhost, node-modules, express-subdomain

I created a test app for using subdomains.
it is not woking. when get `api.localhost:3000` it shows `localhost:3000`...
***index.js:***

```
var subdomain = require('express-subdomain');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

app.get("/", (req, res)=>{
    res.send("silav")
})
//routers 
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
   res.send('Welcome to our API!');
});

router.get('/users', function(req, res) {
    res.json([
        { name: "Brian" }
    ]);
});

app.use(subdomain("api", router));
app.listen(3000)
```

and lines of edited `etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       api.localhost
::1             localhost
```

***thanks***

Comment: Did you grant writes permission to your hosts file? And what OS are you using?

Comment: it is windows 10. and I can edit it.

Comment: try ping `api.localhost` and check.

Comment: it said sent = 4, received = 4.

Comment: If it returns that then it should work

Comment: This still needs more clarification. Super frustrated with the lack of docs on this library for Windows 10. I did get the sub domain working, but example.com and api.example.com still return the same thing that is in the app.get and having multiple subdomains is still a no go.